# How do I add a the bootstrap 'form-control' class to a select using the Simple_Form gem?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

As my title explains, I have a select box in my form using Simple Form. All I'd like to do, is have it look like this bootstrap example under the selects section here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

```
<%= f.input :category_id, label: 'Category: ' do %>
   <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true %>
```

As far as I can see I'd only have to add the 'form-control' class. But I can't figure out how to set the class.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true, input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

The 'input_html' property is what you want to use.

Comment: While this would indeed add the `form-control` class to an individual input, it is not the Right Way to do this and would not in and of itself produce Bootstrappy forms, as there are other Bootstrap classes to be applied to buttons, labels, inline help, etc that would still be missing.

Comment: That's right, it's been a while. Have to use `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap` to install simple form in the first place, too.

Comment: Thanks. I had the bootstrap extention installed allready. I figured out how to do it though: I just needed to add this '...{}, class: 'form-control',...'. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score -1):

As of writing, Bootstrap 3 is only supported by the pre-releases of simple_form v3.1, the latest of which you can use by specifying this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc2', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'
```

From there you can just follow the instructions [in the docs here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap).